# Fabric Crashlytics How to upload dSYM file in Jenkins with Xcode integration plugin

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

ok, I use Jenkins + Xcode integration plugin to auto export iPA for tester to test.  I want Jenkins to auto upload dSYM file to fabric server on every build.  How to do it?

Jenkins is running on my mac mini 2012 with mac os 10.11.1.   I have install fabric.app on it, and the app is always running, and the project have a shell

```
./Fabric.framework/run xxxkey  xxx
```

But it sees not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I find the problem is that the upload dSYM process is killed by jenkins.  Jenkins kills all process spawn by the job. I am solving this problem.

To solve it, read the document:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ProcessTreeKiller

just add a variable

```
export BUILD_ID=dontKillMe
```

And the upload dSYM task will continue to upload.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the answer above, you simple append the BUILD_ID to the beginning of the call.  I was building a macOS/iOS project, so used the following within the "Build Phases" section:

```
BUILD_ID=dontKillMe ./Fabric.framework/run xxxkey  xxx
```

This worked a treat for me.

Comment: Fixed it for me too.