# Jenkins and Fastlane: Uploading dSYM to Fabric for my macOS app never gets executed

Tags: macos, jenkins, crashlytics, fastlane, dsym

My situation: Jenkins runs a Fastlane script as a root user which builds the macOS project (Release configuration).
There is a build phase:

```
if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" = "Release" ]; then
echo 'Crashlytics executing...'
"${PROJECT_DIR}/Frameworks/Fabric.framework/run" xxx yyy
echo 'Crashlytics run completed.'
fi
```

In the Console Output, there is a line:

```
▸ Running script 'Crashlytics'
```

but the actual dSYM never gets uploaded as I always have to manually drop it in the `fabric.io` dSYM upload page.

Did anyone have similar issues?
What would be acceptable for me is if I could use the `uploadDSYM` script to upload dSYM but trying to run it reports an error like:

```
warning: using uploadDSYM directly to upload dSYMs is not supported. uploadDSYM will be deprecated in a future release.error: Fabric: Failed to Detect Build Environment
```

Comment: Just run into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33622614. Could help?

Comment: I'd like to determine if this is a fastlane specific issue. Can you call https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/missing-dsyms.html#upload-symbols-script

Comment: @ToddBurner That upload-symbols script isn't available if you manually integrate Crashlytics.framework. Where are we supposed to get it?